# In Pandas, how can I duplicate all rows with a specific value in a column, changing that columns value in the duplicate?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have set of data from a DB imported into pandas, that includes a `type` column.  `type` can either be 'no-extra', or 'has-extra'.  What I want to do is duplicate every row in the DataFrame where the `type` value is 'has-extra', and in the duplicate row, I want to set this value to 'EXTRA'.  So if I start with this data:

```
data = [
    {'id': 1, 'type': 'no-extra'},
    {'id': 2, 'type': 'has-extra'},
    {'id': 3, 'type': 'no-extra'},
    {'id': 4, 'type': 'has-extra'}
]
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to end up with:

```
result = [
    {'id': 1, 'type': 'no-extra'},
    {'id': 2, 'type': 'has-extra'},
    {'id': 2, 'type': 'EXTRA'},
    {'id': 3, 'type': 'no-extra'},
    {'id': 4, 'type': 'has-extra'},
    {'id': 4, 'type': 'EXTRA'}
]
result_df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

NOTE- the id in this case is not the index for the DataFrame, but rather is a key that can be used to look up the original data in the DB.  Any thoughts on how to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html), [`DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
extra = data_df[data_df['type'].eq('has-extra')].copy()
extra['type'] = 'EXTRA'
data_df = data_df.append(extra).sort_values('id').reset_index(drop=True)

   id       type
0   1   no-extra
1   2  has-extra
2   2      EXTRA
3   3   no-extra
4   4  has-extra
5   4      EXTRA
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df_final = (pd.concat([data_df, data_df[data_df.type.eq('has-extra')].assign(type='EXTRA')])
              .sort_values('id').reset_index(drop=True))

Out[641]:
   id       type
0   1   no-extra
1   2  has-extra
2   2      EXTRA
3   3   no-extra
4   4  has-extra
5   4      EXTRA
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['type'] == 'has-extra',:]
df1['type'] = 'EXTRA'
result_df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_values(by='id').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   id       type
0   1   no-extra
1   2  has-extra
2   2      EXTRA
3   3   no-extra
4   4  has-extra
5   4      EXTRA
```